Having trouble using the F1 score as a metric in keras tuner
I need to use the F1 score as a metric for my hyperparameter tuner but I get the following error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
This is my code, I am using the RNN, GRU and LSTM architectures.
Here in this case the num_classes=3

class MyHyperModel(keras_tuner.HyperModel):
    def build(self, hp):
        labels = list(map(int, np.unique(data.label)))
        num_classes = len(labels)
        layer_num = hp.Int("hidden_layers", 1, 4)
        bidirectional = hp.Boolean("bidirectional")
        lr = hp.Choice("learning_rate", values=[0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])
        units = hp.Int("hidden_units", min_value=10, max_value=150, step=10)
        model_type = hp.Choice("model_type", values=["RNN", "GRU", "LSTM"])
        dropout = 0.15
        
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([layers.Input(shape = input_shape)])
        
        for i in range(layer_num):
            if model_type == "RNN":
                layer = layers.SimpleRNN(units=units, activation="tanh", return_sequences=i < layer_num - 1)
            elif model_type == "GRU":
                layer = layers.GRU(units=units, activation="tanh", return_sequences=i < layer_num - 1)
            elif model_type == "LSTM":
                layer = layers.LSTM(units=units, activation="tanh", return_sequences=i < layer_num - 1)
    
            if bidirectional:
                layer = layers.Bidirectional(layer)
    
            model.add(layer)  
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout))    
                
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"))

        model.compile(
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy', keras.metrics.F1Score()],
        )
        
        return model
        
    def fit(self, hp, model, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        batch_size = 32
        
        return model.fit(x, y, batch_size=batch_size, *args, **kwargs)

I am using the Bayesian Optimization method
tuner = keras_tuner.BayesianOptimization(
    MyHyperModel(),
    max_trials=1800,
    objective=keras_tuner.Objective(keras.metrics.F1Score(), direction="max"),
    directory='output/'+target+'_final',
    project_name='swipping'
)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_f1_score', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True, mode='max')

tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[callback])

Here is the error in more detail:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[64], line 3
      1 callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_f1_score', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True, mode='max')
----> 3 tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[callback])

File ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py:234, in BaseTuner.search(self, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    232     self.on_trial_begin(trial)
    233     self._try_run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
--> 234     self.on_trial_end(trial)
    235 self.on_search_end()

File ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py:338, in BaseTuner.on_trial_end(self, trial)
    332 def on_trial_end(self, trial):
    333     """Called at the end of a trial.
    334 
    335     Args:
    336         trial: A `Trial` instance.
    337     """
--> 338     self.oracle.end_trial(trial)
    339     self.save()

File ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/oracle.py:108, in synchronized.<locals>.wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    106     LOCKS[oracle].acquire()
    107     THREADS[oracle] = thread_name
--> 108 ret_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
    109 if need_acquire:
    110     THREADS[oracle] = None

File ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/oracle.py:586, in Oracle.end_trial(self, trial)
    584 if not self._retry(trial):
    585     self.end_order.append(trial.trial_id)
--> 586     self._check_consecutive_failures()
    588 self._save_trial(trial)
    589 self.save()

File ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/oracle.py:543, in Oracle._check_consecutive_failures(self)
    541     consecutive_failures = 0
    542 if consecutive_failures == self.max_consecutive_failed_trials:
--> 543     raise RuntimeError(
    544         "Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit "
    545         f"of {self.max_consecutive_failed_trials}.\n"
    546         + (trial.message or "")
    547     )

RuntimeError: Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit of 3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/lweber/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py", line 273, in _try_run_and_update_trial
    self._run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/home/users/lweber/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py", line 238, in _run_and_update_trial
    results = self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/home/users/lweber/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner.py", line 314, in run_trial
    obj_value = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, *args, **copied_kwargs)
  File "/home/users/lweber/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner.py", line 233, in _build_and_fit_model
    results = self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_3812153/3145055833.py", line 41, in fit
    return model.fit(x, y, batch_size=batch_size, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/users/lweber/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/users/lweber/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/callbacks.py", line 2108, in on_epoch_end
    if self._is_improvement(current, self.best):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()```



I tried using a custom F1 function as well as the built-in function tfa.metric.F1Score(). Both didn't change the outcome. 

